# How to copy powershell responses to command?

Tags: powershell

I wanted to copy the response of `powercfg /l` with a command, not manual. But I cannot figure it out how to copy the response. So when I type the command, what I hope is that the response copied to my cliboard

For example:
If I type powercfg /l this is the response

```
Existing Power Schemes (* Active)

Power Scheme GUID: 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e  (Balanced)
Power Scheme GUID: 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c  (High performance)
Power Scheme GUID: a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a  (Power saver)
```

I wanted that the response of `powercfg /l` to be copied in my clipboard, is there anyway to do that in powershell?

Comment: `powercfg /l | clip` or `powercfg /l | set-clipboard`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in windows command `clip.exe` or PowerShell's `Set-Clipboard`:

```
# Using clip.exe
powercfg /l | clip

# Using Set-Clipboard
powercfg /l | Set-Clipboard
```

Comment: Thank you much for the info, Hope you the best

Answer (score 0):

This one is more wordy, but it retrieve an PSObject, not only text :

```
function Get-PowerSchemes
{
   Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\User\PowerSchemes\ | 
      Where { Get-ChildItem -Path $_.PSPath } | 
      Select @{Label="Guid";Expression={ $_.PSChildName }}, 
             @{Label="FriendlyName";Expression={ ((Get-ItemProperty -Path $_.PSPath -Name FriendlyName).FriendlyName -split ',')[2] }}, 
             @{Label="IsActive";Expression={ $_.PSChildName -eq (Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\User\PowerSchemes\ -Name ActivePowerScheme).ActivePowerScheme }}
}


Get-PowerSchemes | Set-Clipboard
```

So you can easily retrieve active scheme for example

```
Get-PowerSchemes | Where IsActive | Set-Clipboard
```

or even only his GUID

```
(Get-PowerSchemes | Where IsActive).Guid | Set-Clipboard
```